# Limit number of selections in a MultiSelect ListBox

Tags: vba, ms-access

Is there a way to limit the number of selections a user can choose on a ListBox with MultiSelect enabled in Access 2003?  Right now I have a procedure that fires on the On Click event that checks the number of choices selected and if it is over my threshold it will display a warning label.

Comment: Just a comment as OP specifies they have MultiSelect enabled, but I went down the rabbit hole of functions/checking/clearing before realizing there was a setting to make the ListBox `SingleSelect` lol... See https://analysistabs.com/vba-code/activex-controls/listbox/p/multiselect/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give this a try.  It basically deselects the last item selected if its over the predefined limit:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()

Dim counter         As Integer
Dim selectedCount   As Integer

selectedCount = 0

For counter = 1 To ListBox1.ListCount Step 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(counter - 1) = True Then 'selected method has 0 base
        selectedCount = selectedCount + 1
    End If
Next counter

If selectedCount >= 4 Then 'modify # here
    ListBox1.Selected(ListBox1.ListIndex) = False 'listindex returns the active row you just selected
    MsgBox "Limited to 4 Choices", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Retry:"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you.  ListBox.Selected(ListBox.ListIndex) was what I was looking for.

Comment: Actually no that doesn't deselect the last item selected.  It will dselect the last item in the list though which may not be visible.  

Also you can get the exact list using the following rather than having to check each listbox item:  

Me.List11.ItemsSelected.Count

Comment: aha, i knew there was a quicker way to return the selected count! 

I don't follow how it returns the last item in the list... listIndex returns the active index number in the list, unless there is no index selected, then it returns the count of the list.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa196331(office.11).aspx

Comment: He is correct.  ListBox.Selected(ListBox.ListIndex) = False deselects the last item selected.  Just tested it out myself.  You are correct about ItemsSelected.Count though :)

Comment: Ah, ok, now that I think about it I see where I'm wrong.  The ListIndex is the key.

Comment: This causes some undesirable behavior when shift-selecting more than one at a time/more than the limit set. The `MsgBox` alert appears multiple times as `ListBox1.Selected(ListBox1.ListIndex) = False` retriggers the sub at each call. Also, it does not appear to properly clear each selection, only the last item clicked whilst holding the shift key. Unfortunately, I don't have an alternative solution, though I am looking into it.

Comment: Thanks this really worked for me too. Thanks to everyone for their contribution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the listbox BeforeUpdate event to see the listbox.ItemsSelected.Count value. 
If this is over your limit then you unselect (with listbox.Selectec(item)=False) the current one and cancel the event.

Here's an example : 

    `Private Sub lstItems_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)`

```
' Warn the user that only x items can be selected.
' ------------------------------------------------
If lstItems.ItemsSelected.Count > MAX_SELECTED_ITEM_PERMITTED Then
    MsgBox "You can only select " & MAX_SELECTED_ITEM_PERMITTED & " items in this list.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Error"

    ' Unselect previously selected item.
    ' ----------------------------------
    lstItems.Selected(lstItems.ListIndex) = False
    Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you write a very basic example of this?

Answer (score 1):

Using the listbox ItemsSelected collection?  That's the only way that I know of to limit the number of selected items.   OTOH there are some truly twisted individuals  out there who might have figured out an alternative so I never say never.

What's the problemw with this method?

Comment: I presume the OP would like to either prevent more than N selection from being selected or at least be able to deselect the most recent selection when they kick back their error/warning message.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that a much more manageable, user-friendly and understandable UI for this would be the paired listbox approach, with ADD> and  button after the user has reached the limit. You don't have to do anything difficult, just check the ListCount of the right-hand listbox and disable the ADD> button when it reaches the limit.

And you avoid many problems as it's quite clear to the user what they are doing in comparison to selecting multiple items at once in a single listbox. You could make the lefthand listbox multiselect and simply disable the ADD> button if the ItemsSelected count exceeds the limit, and notify the user appropriately.